Django Channels - Live Chat does not Update Messages
Very new to Django and channels. I tried to create a channel system for users to chat with other users, one-on-one. What should I do? I'm also not sure if this is a Javascript thing or the consumers.py issue.
{{ profile.user.username|json_script:"json-sendername" }}
{{ receiver_profile.user.username|json_script:"json-receivername" }}

<script>
    const senderName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-sendername').textContent);
    const receiverName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-receivername').textContent);

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/chat/' + senderName + '/' + receiverName + '/'
    );

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('onmessage')

        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

        if (data.message) {
            let html;
            if (data.sender == senderName) {
                html = 
                `<div class="flex justify-end">
                    <div class="mr-4">
                        <div class="bg-blue-300 p-3 rounded text-lg">${data.message}</div>
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 text-right">${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="${data.profile_picture}" alt="Avatar" class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full">
                </div>`;      
            } else {
                html = 
                `<div class="flex">
                    <img src="${data.profile_picture}" alt="Avatar" class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full">
                    <div class="ml-4">
                        <div class="bg-gray-300 p-3 rounded text-lg">${data.message}</div>
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">${data.timestamp}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
            }
            document.querySelector('#chat-messages').innerHTML += html;
        } else {
            alert('The message was empty!');
        }
    }

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log('onclose')
    }

    document.querySelector("#chat-message-submit").onclick = function(e) {
        const messageInput = document.querySelector("#chat-message-input");
        const message = messageInput.value;

        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'senderName': senderName,
            'receiverName': receiverName
        }))

        messageInput.value = '';
    }
</script>

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat(self, content, sender, recipient):
        return Message.objects.create(senderUsername=sender, content=content, recipientUsername=recipient)

    async def connect(self):
        self.sender_username = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['profile_username']
        self.receiver_username = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['receiver_profile_username']

        self.room_group_name = f'chat_{self.sender_username}_{self.receiver_username}'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        sender = self.sender_username
        recipient = self.receiver_username

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.room_group_name, {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message,
            'sender': sender,
            'recipient': recipient
        })
        
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        sender = event['sender']
        recipient = event['recipient']

        await self.create_chat(message, sender, recipient)

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'sender': sender,
            'recipient': recipient
        }))

Thanks for your help in advance :-)
The messages are being sent through but the only thing is that the messages don't get sent immediately, the other user has to refresh to see the most recent messages.
